# php & mysql setup on Linux

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I am learning Linux, MySQL (setup) and php, all in one go. Slowly getting the hang of it but I am trying to build the structure for my site and I can't seem to get the connection to my database which I have moved to `/var/www/html/site_01/_database/` and the page that is trying to connect to is located at `/var/www/html/site_01/_html/` I have been on W3Schools and quite a few other sites giving tutorials on php and everywhere states `$servername = "localhost";` but I am still unsure if I need to edit the config files of php or MySQL to have the dir of my database added?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question? please check `whathaveyoutried.com` before posting a question

Comment: What exactly do you have in the `_database` dir? You probably want to leave the database to MySQL and not mess around with its files. You should also add your db connection code and any errors you get to the post.

Comment: Thaks, I will give `whathaveyoutried.com` a read. Never come accross that site before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are  probably mistaking URL/URI with phisical path.
You do not need to have your database in any particular directory. As long as its up and running on the same machine as your application server (e.g.:`MAMP`,`XAMP`,pure `apache`,etc) you will be on `localhost`.

All you need to do is connect to your database on your PHP algorithms, with the correct driver for your DBSM on your project and imported.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
```

with the correct `mysql_user` and `mysql_password`

Comment: I think one should avoid using mysql_*, especially in tutorials and when helping others.

Comment: I am sorry, but why?

Comment: ty, I think I will leave it for now where MySQL makes it. Maybe trying to move it was trying to run before I could walk.

Comment: Because it's outdated and removed from PHP. Using it makes it unnecessary hard to avoid sql injection and when half the stackoverflow community going straight into "you should update your code" mode when some question contains it then that should apply for answers as well.

Comment: @JimL, you mean that we shoud use mysqli and PDO instead? I Agree. Sorry for the outdated method.

Comment: Sorry - I am using `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`

Comment: No problem. If its not working maybe you have something wrong with your credentials.
Check if the database is up and running, and check if your username and password are correct.